# how to use custom page template in a page?

Tags: templates, page-template

I have a custom page template, and I want to use this in my page. I have created a new page and in template choose custom page template name. It's working, but I have added 4 blocks in my page, and this not working.

I want to use the custom page template with wordpress page text.
I want to use both custom page template and text blocks as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template should include [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) so that content from your editor is displayed in your page.

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

It would be better if you posted the php code of the page template you created, to find the exact issue.

Comment: thanks , please let me know how can i include content of specific page in `custom template` before `<?php get_footer();?>`

Comment: include the id of the page to get the specific page content <?php echo get_the_content($page_id); ?>

Comment: Thanks, working now